# jQuery on wrong selector calling function

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have dynamic content that I use `on(...)` with the following code, which manages tagging for users - the idea is to dynamically build the tagging menu (it is used on multiple pages), and then allow users to add tags:

```
function tagging(){
    _this = this
    this.build_content = function(){
    //build tagging menu
    ...
    _this.bind_triggers
    }
    this.bind_triggers = function(){
        _this.$I_tag_add = $('#I_add_user_tag');
        _this.$B_tag_add = $('#B_add_user_tag');
        $(document).on('click', _this.$B_tag_add, _this.add_user_tag);
    this.add_user_tag = function(){
        //add user tag
        ...
    }
}
```

`$I_tag_add` is an input box
`$B_tag_add` is a button

When I click `$I_tag_add` to enter a tag to add, `_this.add_user_tag` is called, but I expected this to only happen upon clicking `$B_tag_add`.

I have worked around this by doing:

```
_this.$B_tag_add = $('#B_add_user_tag').click(_this.add_user_tag);
```

which is in fact better code than I previously had - but would like to know whats up with my previous code? Am I missing some oddity with `.on(...)` ?

Comment: suspecting delegated events firing, but can't tell the answer unless I see your code.

Comment: If you want to execute `_this.bind_triggers` in `tagging.buildContent()` you will need to call it with parentheses: `_this.bind_triggers()`.